# In emacs, how do I highlight the current line in the current frame only?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Emacs (23 on Mac Leopard), I've discovered how to highlight the current line with hl-line-mode, but when using it globally in all buffers, it highlights the current line in all buffers in all frames.

I'd like to be able to highlight the current line (or at least have a different face for it) in only the currently active buffer.  I'm sure this must be possible to some degree as the cursor changes dependent on whether the buffer is the current one or not.

Thanks

Singletoned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for `hl-line-mode`, it appears that you might have the variable `hl-line-sticky-flag` turned on.  Try

```
C-h v hl-line-sticky-flag
```

to see if it's non-nil, and if so, then add

```
(setq hl-line-sticky-flag nil)
```

to your .emacs.

Comment: Ok.  I'm embarrassed now.  I thought I'd read all the documentation for hl-line-mode.  Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be set to `t` by default. Wierd.

Comment: @monotux It is set to `t` by default in the library itself (Emacs 23.2).